# Programmatically insert current branch into command

Tags: bash, git

Say I want to run the command:

```
git reset --hard origin/abc
```

where `abc` is my current branch. How can I programmatically insert the current branch into the command instead of having to run `git branch --show`, copying the result, and pasting into the `reset` command?

Comment: Something like `git reset --hard origin/$(git branch --show-current)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git reset --hard origin/$(git branch --show-current)` is the answer thanks to @accdias

Answer (score 2):

You can target the upstream of any branch with `<branch>@{u}`, and the upstream of your current branch with `@{u}` (more details than you want to in [`git help gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem))

So you can reset to your upstream with :

```
git reset --hard @{u}  # if on Windows: quote "@{u}" on Powershell and cmd.exe
```